# R post/postform upload issue

Tags: r, authentication, curl, oauth, httr

I am trying to upload a file to a platform via an API

CUrl request from terminal works fine

```
curl -v --trace-ascii trace.txt -H "Authorization: Bearer XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX" -F "file=@test1234.txt;type=text/txt" https://xxx.YYYY/upload
```

But in R when I use the Post I get status 500 error

```
outfilename="/Volumes/Work/texttest.txt"


POST(url="https://xxx.YYYY/upload",body = upload_file(
path =  outfilename,
type = 'text/txt'),
verbose(),add_headers(Authorization=paste0("Bearer     ",btoken$access_token)))
```

or

```
postForm(uri="https://xxx.YYYY/upload",file = fileUpload(
filename =  outfilename, contentType = 'text/txt'),
add_headers(Authorization=paste0("Bearer ",btoken$access_token)))
```

Can anyone help please ?

EDIT: Got it to work with postForm, will be great if someone helps on why it does not work with POST

```
httpheader <- c(Authorization=paste0("Bearer ",btoken$access_token))
status<-postForm(uri=paste0(server,"upload"),file = fileUpload(filename =  outfilename),.opts=list(httpheader=httpheader))
```

Answer (score 0):

For `POST`, the most similar translation is

```
POST(url="https://xxx.YYYY/upload",
  body = list(file=upload_file(
    path =  outfilename,
    type = 'text/txt')
  ),
  verbose(),
  add_headers(Authorization=paste0("Bearer XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX"))
)
```

Notice how the `body=` is a list. This submits the data as form-data which is what the `curl -F` option does.

Note that I find that using a site like http://requestb.in/ can make it easier to troubleshoot these problems. By posting to that site, you can see exactly what is sent to the server and see how the request different between the two methods.